# grep and replace matching text in same file

Tags: command-line, grep

I am using grep to pull the contents in a file and writing it in output. I wish to concatenate a text for all those pulled entries. Currently, I am doing it in two steps: 1. grep, 2. Modify the text output in excel.

```
grep -E -w "entry1" file1 >output.csv
```

In output.csv I get four lines matching

```
A, entry1
B, entry1
C, entry1
D, entry1
```

I am opening this file in excel and modifying the row header in column1 to

```
A_type1, entry1
B_type1, entry1
C_type1, entry1
D_type1, entry1
```

Is it possible to do the same thing in single line?

Comment: yes of course, probably with awk. Could you provide a sample of your `file1`?

Answer (score 1):

according to the grep output you given, I think this line should help:

```
awk -F, '$2~/entry1/{print $1"_type1" FS $2}' file
```

Comment: @fedorqui quick & dirty fix.. :) same as OP's grep now

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

`$ grep -E "A|B" sample.txt | perl  -pe 's/A/A_type1/g; s/B/B_type1/g'`

This will filter the input file and apply the transformation on the output. The input file remains unchanged.

If you would rather perform an inplace repalcement in the file without affecting the other lines, you could use "sed". In this case the input file does get updated.

`sed -i 's/A/A_type1/g; s/B/B_typ2/g' sample.txt`

```
admin@DESKTOP-J2E0MU7 /cygdrive/c/workspace/temp
$ cat sample.txt
A line
B file
C test1
D sample
E something else
F what
G else
A other line
B second occurence

admin@DESKTOP-J2E0MU7 /cygdrive/c/workspace/temp
$ grep -E "A|B" sample.txt | perl  -pe 's/A/A_type1/g; s/B/B_type1/g'
A_type1 line
B_type1 file
A_type1 other line
B_type1 second occurence
```

Comment: This would not solve the purpose. Because, there might be 100s of entries corresponding to /entry1/. Then excel way would be better !

Answer (score 0):

A different solution using awk to append "_type1" to column1 of whatever comes out of grep.

`$ grep -E "A|B" sample.txt | awk '{$1=$1"_type";print}''\`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '{print $1"_type1",$2}' OFS=, file

A_type1, entry1
B_type1, entry1
C_type1, entry1
D_type1, entry1
```